# Erro ao enviar uma requisição POST via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom dia, estou tentando enviar uma requisição POST para uma URL porém estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>   O JSON está correto na formatação pois cheguei validar o mesmo.
>   O código está assim:

```
function salvaDados(){
  var myData = JSON.stringify('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}')
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:81/adm/dados",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',        
    data: myData,
    success: function(data){
        alert('ok')
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown)
    }
  })
}
```

o servidor REST está normal pois consigo salvar este mesmo JSON via postman.

Comment: Cara o método **JSON.stringify()** é utilizado para transformar um Json válido em uma `string`, repare que o que vc está inserindo dentro do método já é uma string!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, quando faço JSON.parse, acontece o mesmo erro.

Comment: O que o @LeAndrade referiu é que deves remover `'` no exemplo que deste, pois estás a tentar converter uma string e näo um objeto... testa `var myData = JSON.stringify({ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"});`

Comment: @Sergio, fiz como falou e o erro mudou, agora está dando (SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom acho que vc não entendeu muito bem o conceito desses métodos para **JSON**, para vc enviar dados para o back-end utilizando o **[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** o Json precisa estar em um formato válido, repare que no seu código o que realmente está passando para o método é uma **`string`**, por isso o erro:

```
var myData = JSON.stringify('{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}')
```

Quando o correto seria passar um Json válido:

```
var myData = JSON.stringify({"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"})
```

OU:

```
var myData = {"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}
var jsonSt = JSON.stringify(myData)
```

Como pode ver no exemplo abaixo passando os dados corretamente os métodos funcionam:

```js
var myData = { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"};
var jsonSt = JSON.stringify(myData);

console.log('Tipo do myData: ', typeof myData);
console.log('myData: ', myData);

console.log('-------');

console.log('Depois do stringify: ', typeof jsonSt);
console.log('jsonSt: ', jsonSt);
```

O mesmo serve para o **[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**:

```js
var myData = { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"};
var jsonSt = JSON.stringify(myData);
var jsonPa = JSON.parse(jsonSt);

console.log('Depois do stringify: ', typeof jsonSt);
console.log('jsonSt: ', jsonSt);
console.log('-------');
console.log('Parseando para objeto: ', typeof myData);
console.log('jsonPa: ', jsonPa);
```